# xml parsing in iOS with too many tags with the same name

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, xml-parsing

I have got the xml parsing, but a bit difficult to parse the xml below
thanks for your suggestions

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AllJobs>
    <Mainjobs>
     <job1 name="simple">
     <Group name="one">
        <item name>"itemone"</item name>
        <item name>"itemtwo"</item name>
        <item name>"itemthree"</item name>
      </Group>
      <Group name="two">
        <item name>"itemfour"</item name>
        <item name>"itemfive"</item name>
        <item name>"itemsix"</item name>
      </Group>
    </job1>
    <job2 name="medium" />
    </job2>
    <job3 name="hard" />
    </job3>
    </Mainjobs>
</AllJobs>
```

from the above xml i am trying to parse the below item names that are "itemFour,item five,item six" and displaying them in a tableview

```
<Group name="two">
    <item>"itemfour"</item>
    <item>"itemfive"</item>
    <item>"itemsix"</item>
```

i am parsing like this but it is retrieving all the items names in every group tag

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Alljobs"]){
    jobNameArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

}else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Mainjobs"]){
    //  self.itemDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    object=[[parseObject alloc]init];
    dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
}
      else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Group"])
    {
 if ([str isEqualToString:@"Two"]) {
            currentElement=nil;
            currentElement=[[NSMutableString alloc]init];
        }
    }
   else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"])
    {
        str=[attributeDict objectForKey:@"name"];
        NSLog(@"the attribute string is %@",[attributeDict objectForKey:@"name"]);
    }
```

}

```
   -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
    if(string){
            [currentElement appendString:string];
    NSLog(@"  the element00000000%@", currentElement);
}
```

}

```
    -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:    (NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Mainjobs"]){
        NSLog(@"the array count is %i",[jobNameArray count]);
}
else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Job1"])
{

}
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"</item>"])
{
            NSLog(@"element ---------%@",elementName);

[jobNameArray addObject:str];
}
```

Comment: which XPL parser ur using now?

Comment: Can we see what you have attempted and what does not work?

Comment: i am using NSXMLPrser -Ganapathy

Answer (score 0):

By using NSXmlParser this is more difficult because it finds the characters by distinguished tags. I have also faced the same issue way back . That time I solved this by maintaining the depth variable.By looking towards your xml that job attribute is not seems to be ok for me because **if you have n numbers of the job then on which basis you gone compare those ?** But in your case I think you can achieve as follow:

1. Make a class named job.
2. job class having following properties:

   jobName:NSString;
   groupName:NSString;
   items:NSMutableArray;
3. Add this Job object to the array .